# Trying to connect Terminal to recognize "mate" command for TextMate

Tags: macos, bash, textmate

> Couldn't Create Link
>
> Creating the link “/usr/bin/mate” failed with the following reason: Operation not permitted

I am getting this error when I attempt to link the terminal usage with TextMate. 
I did this by going Help >> Terminal Usage... 
And I tried to create a link in /usr/bin.

I think the problem is something to do with permission issue.
I am wondering if there is a way to work around this problem by changing bash file directly or something and make terminal recognize "mate" as a command.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: how are you attempting to create a link?  from within a Terminal command line?  or something built into TextMate?  You can't create links in /usr/bin without being authenticated as root.

Comment: TextMate has Terminal Usage feature built in. It is suppose to take care of creating alias "mate" to open TextMate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming Textmate is installed in `/Applications` the following command in the terminal should manually create the link for you:

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate /usr/bin
```

The command will ask you for your user account's password so it has the permissions necessary to create the link in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: TextMate 2 appears to install the link, but there's no 'mate': `$ which mate
/usr/local/bin/mate/usr/local/bin/mate` then on trying `mate filename` - `line 2: exec: /Contents/Resources/mate: cannot execute: No such file or directory` and SharedSupport just contains 'Bundles' - any ideas?

Comment: @DaveEveritt in Textmate 2 you need to go to Preferences -> Terminal and then just click on Install.
http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/11/09/textmate-2-basics/

Comment: Thanks, but I've done that. The issue for me is that the 'mate' command isn't present at all in my installation of TextMate2. Macromates suggested downloading a newer build of TextMate2, but it's no longer supported on Snow Leopard

Comment: The link is now here: ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 3):

There should be an option to create it in `/usr/local/bin`. Create it there. Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I was able to create a link in `/usr/local/bin` successfully. How do I add `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH`?

Comment: @garbagecollection `cd` to your root, `vim ./.bashrc` and then press `i` to go to insert mode, and then type `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and then type `:wq`